# Show X latest posts from custom post type

Tags: wordpress, custom-post-type

If I have a custom post type, e.g. "Movies", how do I echo the 5 latest posts from this custom post type.

I've tried

```
<?php
$type = 'movies';
$args=array(
  'post_type' => $type,
  'post_status' => 'publish',
  'posts_per_page' => -5,
  'caller_get_posts'=> 5

$my_query = null;
$my_query = new WP_Query($args);
if( $my_query->have_posts() ) {
  while ($my_query->have_posts()) : $my_query->the_post(); ?>
    <p><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark" title="Permanent Link to <?php the_title_attribute(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></p>
    <?php
  endwhile;
}
wp_reset_query();  // Restore global post data stomped by the_post().
?>
```

This doesn't return anything though

Comment: hi it's working fine just close the array of $args.

Comment: Please go through **all** of your past questions and select "correct" answers (using the check mark next to the answer) where appropriate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have multiple syntax errors in the code you've shared.

To answer your question, `posts_per_page` should be a **positive** integer, and `caller_get_posts` should be removed (it was deprecated years ago).

```
$args=array(
  'post_type' => 'movies',
  'post_status' => 'publish',
  'posts_per_page' => 5,
);

$my_query = new WP_Query($args);
```

Answer (score 1):

This will pull most recent post from your custom post type

```
 $new_loop = new WP_Query( array(
'post_type' => 'movies',
'posts_per_page' => 5 // put number of posts that you'd like to display
) );
```

//wrong 'posts_per_page' => -5